# Flashing same menu on clicking of every menu, by using context menu function?

Tags: vue.js

We are using java script, facing some issues by using context menu function. We have inbox tab, in that opening 80 messages, and draft tab opening 100 messages.

On right of inbox message only some menus should flash and same on right clicking 
of draft messages.

But after clicking of both flashing same menus.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Hello Minal, your question is really vague and not understandable. What is your development environment, are you using any packages (dependencies) for your menu? What messages are you talking about? You need to provide more details for anyone to help you.

Comment: If i understand your problem the following may be the solution: 

You may wanna check and see what tags you are using. If you are using `<a></a>` the page will refresh but when you use `<router-link></router-link>` it should stop the flashing.